How to send data from forms -> gallery -> sharepoint?
I have a form application for ordering items, the data is then transferred once the user clicks add to cart by a collect function succesfully into screen 2's vertical gallery. Then I want to click submit and that would submit the entire shopping cart but nothing is getting submitted.
The code for my "Submit" button is:
ForAll(
    Gallery6.AllItems,
    Patch(
        'E-Store',
        Defaults('E-Store'),
        {
            'User name': userName,
            'DOB': dateOfBirth,
            'Item name': itemName,
            ...
        }
    );
    
    
);
Clear(collection1);

I think the issue might be in the Defaults brackets, the left side is autocompleted and the right side I have tried to use directly from my sharepoint list's url in the column section and also from my gallery(the names of the items in the gallery. When I run it sometimes I get a IConvertible implentation error and sometiemes no error but in both times nothing is being sent to sharepoint. I have tried before with SubmitForm() but I want to be able to order mutliple items and then submit it all, one item per row.

So the answer to my issue was that I had to use "ThisRecord" instead of Gallery and also reference the items from my column names from sharepoint(the url).
Examples:
'User name': ThisRecord.userName,
'Submition date': DateValue(subDate),
'DOB': DateValue(DOB),
....


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You should write in the below way-
Also try to remove quotes from SharePoint table's name


ForAll(
    Gallery6.AllItems,
    Patch(
        'E-Store',
        Defaults('E-Store'),
        {
            'User name': Gallery6.ControleName1.Text, //ControleName1 is from your galery's textbox
            'DOB': Gallery6.ControleName2.Text, //ControleName2 is from your galery's dob dtae
            'Item name': Gallery6.ControleName3.Text, //ControleName83 is from your galery's item textbox
            ...
        }
    );
    
    
);
Clear(collection1);



Even there is another tricky and fastest way to PATCH galery items to SharePoint using https://www.matthewdevaney.com/fastest-way-to-patch-all-gallery-items-power-apps/

Dropdown.Selected.
Like ....
Patch(
'Travel Expenses',
LookUp('Travel Expenses', ID=1),
{
Status: Dropdown_Status.Selected
}
)

'User name': Gallery6.Selected.UserName.Text, //ControleName1 is from your galery's textbox
'DOB': Gallery6.Selected.Dateofbirth.Text, //ControleName2 is from your galery's dob dtae
'Item name': Gallery6.Selected.ItemName.Text, //ControleName83 is from your galery's item textbox
...
I did it like so, it wouldn't let me without the "selected", the error I get now is IConvertible...

The issue might be in the transformation of the data types since Item name is a dropdown between 4 choices and I have two date time fields

minutely check the data type. Here better would be, go one by one. So inside the {username..}, keep one properties and then click the button. Not in onetime, there could be TYPO in your code
